# Group isNaN() Code Condensing

Tags: javascript

I have multiple inputs, 16 to be exact. I have a lengthy piece of code that uses isNaN() to check each input:

```
var Qs1 = 0;
var Qs2 = 0;
var Qs3 = 0;
var Qs4 = 0;
var Qs5 = 0;
var Qs6 = 0;
var Qs7 = 0;
var Qs8 = 0;
var Qs9 = 0;
var Qs10 = 0;
var Qs11 = 0;
var Qs12 = 0;
var Qs13 = 0;
var Qs14 = 0;
var Qs15 = 0;
var Qs16 = 0;

if(isNaN(Qs1)) {
      Qs1 = 0;
    }

    if(isNaN(Qs2)) {
      Qs2 = 0;
    }

    if(isNaN(Qs3)) {
      Qs3 = 0;
    }

    if(isNaN(Qs4)) {
      Qs4 = 0;
    }

    if(isNaN(Qs5)) {
      Qs5 = 0;
    }
```

etc, etc.

The thing is that the variables "Qs_" need to change depending on the input. E.g: If the input is 1, Qs_ runs the sum: Qs * 2 * 3; 
(Not the actual code, just an example).

Is there a way I can condense the isNaN() part of my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use an array for the data. it is easy iterable and good to maintain.

Comment: When you have multiple variables with the same name/value type, just store them in an `Array`. `var Qs = new Array(17); qs[1] = 0; ...`

Comment: Would that actually condense the code though? It seems like it wouldn't actually reduce it that much

Comment: Okay, that cut out 16 lines, so thanks for that, but it hasn't answered my isNaN() part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your variables in an array and loop over them:

```js
let qs = []
qs.push(0, 0, 0, 'a')

qs.forEach(function(q, i){
  if (isNaN(q)) qs[i] = 0
})

console.log(qs)
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

@Bill is right- using an array would make this much easier!

So if you had all your Q's defined like:

```
var qs = [0,0,'H',0,'E',0,'Y',0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Then you could just do:

```
qs = qs.map(function(q){ return isNaN(q) ? 0 : q })
```

This will return `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Here's a live example on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/kuvatiwafi/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You could use an implicid casting to number with an unary `+` and check for trutyness. Otherwise return zero.

I suggest to use only variables with starting with lower characters. The uppercase starting is usually left for function which can be used as instance or classes (which is mostly the same).

```js
var qs1 = 0,
    qs2 = -1,
    qs3 = '',
    qs4 = 'q',
    array = [qs1, qs2, qs3, qs4].map(function (a) { return +a || 0; });

console.log(array);
```